# Comparing XML mapping to annotations in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations, mapping

I am migrating a Hibernate project from using mapping files to use annotations. Is there any tool that let me compare both mappings, for example a tool that generate XML mapping files from annotations?

Using another wording. Is there any way to assure that the new annotated project will behave exactly as the project using the mapping files without running it?

Comment: Why do you want to migrate? There are still a few advantages of xml mapping files. Just a minute ago I had to [recommend the usage of xml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15291231/1047269) mappings because annotations sometimes don't offer that flexibility.

Comment: My impression is that they are far easier to learn and use because Java editors like Eclipse offer help and auto completion for annotations. Furthermore annotations in Java code are easier to maintain because you keep related things together and when you change pojos is more difficult to forget that perhaps you have to change mappings as well.