# Java applying annotation conditionally

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have a Spring based project where we turn of features using database flags.

This approach works great when turn on/off new logic. We run into issues when making database changes.
In our testing environment we made have different columns in a given database table, than the table in the production environment.

For example: Let say we have a column `FIELD_IN_TEST_ENV_ONLY` in our testing env only.

```
@Column(name = "FIELD_IN_TEST_ENV_ONLY")
private String myField;
```

When using a JPA repo.

```
this.repo.findAll()
```

The line above will fail if run in an enviroment with out the `FIELD_IN_TEST_ENV_ONLY` column since hibernate will have a column in the select statement that does not exist

So basically I would like to implment something like the following...

```
if(MY_FLAG)
     @Column(name = "FIELD_IN_TEST_ENV_ONLY")
else 
     @Transient
private String myField;
```

I'm just not sure how to implment something like this.

Comment: "In our testing environment we made have different columns than the table in the production environment" <- that's just wrong. What's the point of testing on environment that doesn't represent your prod?

Comment: Try to see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098541/jpa-optional-columns

Comment: @M.Prokhorov sorry maybe I should have explained that better. in our development environment, where we may add a new feature that is not yet ready to be moved to production. We would like to move it to prod behind a flag without making a DDL change unit a go live date where we would add the column.

Comment: That's also strange to say the least. Your go-live should be as atomic as possible, and deploying code without deploying schema is not atomic at all. Also, conditionally applied annotation still means you'll have to redeploy your code to enable the annotation, because it's in your class files.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280789/hibernate-ignore-column-if-not-exist) may help, but I advise you to rethink your approach. Generally speaking, if your app uses JPA, it's a DB-driven app, meaning database should be migrated first, then you app. Not the opposite.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Understood, thank you for the advice.