# Mapping an entity on two different databases with different columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

So i have a situation like this:

A table T is present in two databases. In one of them T has a column C and in the other one it doesn't.
My application reads at deploy time a boolean value which among other things tells it which database it must connect to.

Doing some research it looks like the potential solutions might be:

1. Create two different entities and a parent with MappedSuperclass with all the common properties. One of the sublasses will have that additional column, the other would be "blank". [See comments on the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280789/hibernate-ignore-column-if-not-exist)
2. Create two entities and define two PersistenceUnit for each DB. Then use the schema property of @Table to specify the correct schema.

Are they correct? Any other advice?  Do you know of any drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions are fine. Do whatever works best for you.